# iOS 8.4 + Swift - Custom Transitions from UINavigationController, how can I limit the behavior to only one transition in the Navigation Stack?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uinavigationcontroller, uiviewanimation

I've been dabbling with some very basic custom transitions recently and I'm starting to get the hang of it.  Up until this point, however, I had only made Modal transitions.

I wrote the following code for a basic "Fade" transition from my "Master View" to my "Settings View" (both of which are part of the NavigationController Stack):

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

///Transition manager for transitioning between the loginVC and the content that follows.
class FadeTransition: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        let destinationVC = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey)
        let sourceView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewKey)
        let destinationView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextToViewKey)
        transitionContext.containerView().addSubview(destinationView!)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(self.transitionDuration(transitionContext), animations: { () -> Void in

            sourceView!.alpha = 0.0
            destinationView!.alpha = 1.0
            }) { (didComplete) -> Void in

                println("Fade Transition: \(didComplete)")
                transitionContext.completeTransition(didComplete)
        }
    }

    func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) -> NSTimeInterval {
        return 0.5
    }

    func animationControllerForPresentedController(presented: UIViewController, presentingController presenting: UIViewController, sourceController source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return self
    }

    func animationControllerForDismissedController(dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return self
    }

    func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerForOperation operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, fromViewController fromVC: UIViewController, toViewController toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return self
    }


}
```

I was excited.  I rejoiced.  All appeared to be well until I then went to a different View Controller that also has a segue from the "Master View"...and it had the same transition.  Of course this is to be expected, I just hadn't thought of it.

**How can I limit this transition to only occur between two specific `UIViewControllers`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` method `navigationController(_:animationControllerForOperation:fromViewController:toViewController)`. You have implemented it in your custom transition class above (I would suggest making a more general class your nav controller delegate instead, such as the view controller that contains it or the app delegate), but you return `self` indisciminately, indicating that every transition for that navigation controller should use your fade transition.

Instead, look at the `from/toViewController` parameters to decide whether you want to use a custom transition between those particular view controllers. If you want to use the default animated transition, just return `nil`.

From the [`UINavigationControllerDelegate` Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UINavigationControllerDelegate/navigationController:animationControllerForOperation:fromViewController:toViewController:):

> **Return Value**
>
> The animator object responsible for managing the transition animations,
>   or nil if you want to use the standard navigation controller
>   transitions. The object you return must conform to the
>   UIViewControllerAnimatorTransitioning protocol.